# How do I add PHP to full nodes?

Tags: 7

Is it possible to add PHP bits to nodes? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
<p>Some paragraph I blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla...<p>
<?php Some PHP code I with echo statements ?>
<p>Some paragraph II blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla...<p>
<p>Some paragraph III blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla...<p>
<?php Some PHP code II with echo statements ?>
...
```

If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [PHP Filter](http://drupal.org/node/1046700), but I would highly recommend AGAINST it as it doesn't restrict anything, and with it, your users could enter things far more "exciting" than just echo statements...

Comment: Only one profile will be able to create such nodes, but is there a safer way to achieve this?

Comment: not really, hence the reason that I'd suggest thinking of another solution.